# Float display on Arduino LCD Shield (Nokia 6100)

Tags: arduino, lcd

The Nokia 6100 LCD [Shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) for Arduino only has the `LCDPutStr` command. How do I display floating numbers from my variables?

Comment: I guess you need to convert them to string first.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done it myself but there's a good thread on the topic (of floats to strings for Arduino) [here](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1205038401).

Also, there is the [LiquidCrystal](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystal) library which works well, if it's compatible with the Nokia. You can feed numbers to it's print function.

Remember Arduino's language is simplified C++. So if none of those Arduino solutions work just look for an open source library and nab the function from there.

Comment: No, Arduino uses (a subset of) C++ as the base language, not C (although C can be considered a subset of C++). "[Wiring and Processing have spawned another project, Arduino, which uses the Processing IDE together with a simplified version of the C++ programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_%28development_platform%29#Arduino_and_Fritzing)". See [Writing a Library for Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) for an example using classes."

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Thanks, I hadn't realized it was c++ It always just looked like a duck and quacked like a duck I never took the time to ask it. I will edit my answer.